# How do I constrain this background to the edges of the screen programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jw8IJ.png)

```
UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"giberWallpaper.png"]];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = background;
```

I have looked online on how to constrain a background and I see a lot of jargin, but nothing straight forward on how to set constraints for the top, sides, and bottom edges of the screen equal to 0.

Comment: What do you mean by "edges of the screen"? It looks to me like the background is at the edge of the screen!

Comment: I want to  do the exact thing that you can do in a .xib file by clicking the button and it creating constraints for the top, sides, and bottom with distance from the edge of the screen being 0

Comment: why you just don't put UIImageView at the bottom of view, make it fill all screen and specify margin constraints for it?

Comment: well I tried just putting an image in my xib file as a child of my view and it just pushed my table data down.

Comment: ^don't be a jerk...I am asking for help...If you do not want to help me then just ignore the post

Answer (score 1):

On iOS 8 you can use [Visual Format Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage.html). On iOS 9, you can also use the newer layout anchors API.

There are two approaches here:

1. Anchor all of your edges to the superview, or
2. Center your image in the superview and give it equal height and width to the superview.

Comment: You're welcome. Didn't realize the system would generate that comment. Sorry!